# CodeContracts: false warning "Possibly unboxing a null reference"

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

[image]

In the image above, you can see a warning from Code Contracts. I don't think this is legit, as `this` can never be `null`.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

---

This property is a member of the following class:

```
public class NHibernateIQueryableQueryBase<TEntity, TQuery, TQueryInterface>
    : IQuery<TEntity>, IFluentQueryInterface<TEntity, TQueryInterface>
    where TQuery : NHibernateIQueryableQueryBase<TEntity, TQuery,
                                                 TQueryInterface>,
                   TQueryInterface
    where TQueryInterface : IQuery<TEntity>
```

---

Update:
Changing the property to the following still shows the warning - on the line `return result;`:

```
public TQueryInterface And
{
    get
    {
        var result = this as TQuery;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Complete shot in the dark cause I am a noob and I'm sure you've thought of it but couldn't the cast of TQuery(this) return null?

Comment: Please show us your type declaration.  What constraints do you have on those generic parameters?

Comment: @JesseCarter: No. It could result in an InvalidCastException, so I'd say that is not the reason of the warning.

Comment: @SLaks: Updated the question. I am afraid that is rather complex, but basically, it is guaranteed, that the cast will always succeed.

Comment: I suspect that adding `: class` to the constraints will suppress the warning.

Comment: @SLaks: Indeed. Adding a `class` constraint to `TQueryInterface` removed the warning. Could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: Why are you casting to TQuery instead of TQueryInterface?

Comment: @default.kramer: `TQuery` implements `TQueryInterface` but `this` doesn't. Casting `this` to `TQueryInterface` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis doesn't understand that `this` is guaranteed to implement `TQuery`.
Therefore, it's warning you that you might end up taking a `null` reference to the interface type, and returning it as a `struct` that implements that interface:

You need to add `: class` to the constraints of the `TQueryInterface` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this question](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/remove-null-unboxing-warnings-interface-36547.aspx), I'd say you need to specify what happens if the cast fails.

Try `return this as TQuery` since the `as` operator will return null if the cast fails, whereas the explicit cast will throw an error.